# Unable to clone jQueryUI dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone

I've got page on which a user is adding and editing a list of books.  You can move them around, add new books, edit books already there...

To add or edit each individual book, a dialog pops up containing a form with several input fields: title, author, genre, etc.  I also have the Watermark plugin putting default text into each of these fields.

Rather than iterate over and resetting each of these fields AFTER each book is saved back to the master list and the dialog is closed, in order to get the form ready for the next book, I'm thinking it'd be easier merely to use a clone of the form each time and then merely throw out the clone after each save:

```
$( "#addEditBook" ).click(function() {
$("#bookForm").clone().removeAttr("id").attr("id", "clonedBookForm").insertAfter("#bookForm");
$( "#clonedBookForm" ).dialog( "open" );
return false;
});
```

In FireBug, I can see `#clonedBookForm` being created.  And it's identical to the `#bookForm` below it.

But that next line, `.dialog( "open" );` throws this error:

```
uncaught exception: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

Note: I know the

```
$( "#clonedBookForm" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
etc., etc.
```

...works because it works fine with the original `#bookForm`.  Something about the events not being cloned?

I'd love to get this sorted out, because I'd imagine throw-away clones of things would be a real time-saver...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `bookForm` dialog, that you clones, wraped in another container when you initialize it with

```
$( "#bookForm" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
etc., etc.
```

construction. And then you later clone `bookForm` you clone only wrapped content, without main wrapper. That's why you have no success. Try to use jQuery templates and create new dialog from template.

Comment: CoolEsh, thanks so much for taking the time to help out.  I wonder if I could bother you to a) spell out your point about the wrapped content versus the main wrapper.  In Firebug, I can see #clonedBookForm and #bookForm are identical - child elements, data and all.  And b) could you share a link on jQuery templates?  I'm googling around but keep finding stuff on JTML, which doesn't sound like the same thing...

Comment: a) Let's look at my simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SX5b6/1/ . As you can see I added very simple dialog. But if you look on it with firebug my div with id is nested inside another div without id and you can't handle its parameters;

Comment: b) about templates: I use them for populating system dialogs that allows me do not copy-paste html-code every time when I need dialog on page. `jQuery.template( 'templateName', '<option value="${value}">${title}</option>' );` allows to save template and `jQuery.tmpl( 'templateName', params ).appendTo( someDropdownElement );` allows to pass parameters to template and append html to some element. Please read jQuery API for more detailed info: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=tmpl